# ¿Cómo puedo recibir y guardar una imagen en una vista basada en funciones en Django?

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy intentando hacer un formulario para que el usuario ingrese los datos del perfil de su empresa cuando esta no se haya ingresado por primera vez y que los edite cuando la empresa ya ha sido ingresada. Para esto estoy usando una vista basada en funciones:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
@permission_required('core.change_perfil', login_url='Core:sin_privilegios')
def perfil_crear(request, perfil_id=1):
    perfil = Perfil.objects.first()
    contexto ={}
    form_perfil = {}
    template_name= "core/forms/perfil.html"
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form_perfil = PerfilForm()
        
        if perfil:
            e = {
                'name' : perfil.name,
                'nit' : perfil.nit,
                'logo' : perfil.logo,
                'slogan' : perfil.slogan,
                'legalRep' : perfil.legalRep
            }
            
            form_perfil = PerfilForm(e)

        contexto={'perfil':perfil, 'form_perfil':form_perfil}
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        nit = request.POST.get("nit")
        logo = request.POST.get("logo")
        slogan = request.POST.get("slogan")
        legalRep = request.POST.get("legalRep")

        if not perfil:
            perfil = Perfil(
                name= name,
                nit= nit,
                logo = logo,
                slogan = slogan,
                legalRep = legalRep
            )
            if perfil:
                perfil.save()
        else:
            perfil.name = name
            perfil.nit = nit
            perfil.logo = logo
            perfil.slogan = slogan
            perfil.legalRep = legalRep
            perfil.save()
        
        return redirect("Core:perfil_update", perfil_id=1)
    
    return render(request, template_name, contexto)
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando intento enviar una imagen en el logo de la empresa, esta no se guarda. **Quisiera saber ¿cómo puedo trabajar con imagenes (ImageField) en mis vistas basadas en funciones?** Pues cuando realizo esto en una vista basada en clases funciona perfectamente.

Este es mi modelo de perfil:

```
class Perfil(ClaseModelo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Nombre')
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='NIT', null=True, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Logo', null=True, blank=True)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Eslogan', null=True, blank=True)
    legalRep = models.CharField(max_length=65, verbose_name='Representante legal', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfil'
        ordering = ['id']
```

Estas son mis URLS:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views
app_name='Core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.StartInicio.as_view(), name="inicio"),

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='core/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='core/login.html'), name='logout'),

    path('sin_privilegios/', views.HomeSinPrivilegios.as_view(), name="sin_privilegios"),

    path('perfil/nuevo', views.perfil_crear, name='perfil_create'),
    path('perfil/editar/<int:perfil_id>', views.perfil_crear, name='perfil_update'),
]
```

Y esta es mi plantilla donde renderizo el formulario:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            action="{% if perfil %} {% url 'Core:perfil_update' 1 %} {% else %} {% url 'Core:perfil_create' %} {% endif %}">
            <div class="card card-dark">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Información del perfil de empresa</h3>
                    <div class="card-tools">
                        <!-- Buttons, labels, and many other things can be placed here! -->
                        <!-- Here is a label for example -->
                        <span class="badge badge-primary">Label</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-tools -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="id_name">Nombre:</label>
                            {{form_perfil.name}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6">
                            <label for="id_name">NIT:</label>
                            {{form_perfil.nit}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                            <label for="id_name">Logo:</label>
                            {{form_perfil.logo}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                            <label for="id_name">Eslogan:</label>
                            {{form_perfil.slogan}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-12">
                            <label for="id_name">Representante legal:</label>
                            {{form_perfil.legalRep}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnTest mt-3">
                        <i class="{% ifequal action 'add' %} fas fa-plus{% else %} fas fa-save{% endifequal %}"></i>
                        Enviar
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-footer -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <!-- Logo de la empresa -->
        <div class="card bg-dark">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Logo actual</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src="{{profile.logo}}" alt="logo empresa" class="logo-show">
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Este es mi formulario:

```py
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.visible_fields():
            form.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        exclude = ['fechaCreacion', 'fechaModificacion', 'usuarioCrea', 'usuarioMod', 'estado']
```

Comment: Tenés que configurar donde se guardan las imágenes desde config y urls, también en el models. Ahí te paso como hacerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para manejar archivos en un FBV te dejo un ejemplo sencillo, una vez configurado lo que te comentaban arriba del MEDIA_URL, etc.

```
def agregar_imagen(request):
    """ Agregar imagen """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_subir_imagen(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.imagen = form.cleaned_data['imagen']
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('lista_imagenes')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = form_subir_imagen()

    return render(request, 'template_form.html', {'form': form})

class form_subir_imagen(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Imagen
        fields = ('imagen', 'titulo')
```

Es importante usar request.FILES para poder obtener los archivos que te están mandando a través del post y poder procesarlos y guardarlos. En el ejemplo que te puse, use commit=False para poderle asignar un usuario a la imagen subida y entonces ya proceder a realizar el guardado. Espero esto te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que poner en donde se guardaran las imágenes desde setting.py lo haces en primer instancia con

```
MEDIA_URL =  '/media/' 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

luego en el urls.py de tu app principal agregas un from y el urlpatterns

```
from django.urls import path
from myApp import views
from django.conf import settings <----------


urlpatterns = [
     path('', views.Home, name="Home"),
     ...
     ...
 ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) <-------
```

con solo agregar eso todas las imágenes o media se te van a guardan en una carpeta llamada "media" dentro de tu proyecto, pero si tu quiere separarlo y que las imágenes estén en carpetas separadas para así tener todo un poco mas limpio vas al models y le pones:

```
class MyModels(models.Model): 

    ...

    ...

    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="carpeta1")
```

en ese ejemplo todas las imagen de ese models se te guardaría en "media/carpeta1".
si en otro models quiere que la imagen vaya a otra carpeta sencillamente pones algo mas
Un detalle importante es que no hace falta que crees la carpeta, eso ya lo hace automáticamente Django

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, pero en mi archivo de settings ya tengo puesto todo lo que me dices. Mi problema es que no sé cómo manipular una imagen desde una vista basada en funciones, pues en la que tengo, cuando le doy a guardar simplemente no modifica la imagen existente.